# NullReferenceException on Class array reference

Tags: c++, class, instance, nullreferenceexception

My code is as follows:

```
int main()
{ 
    CProfile **profiles;
    *profiles  = new CProfile[8];
    profiles[0] = new CProfile(2000,2,4);
    profiles[1] = new CProfile(55000,6,50);
    profiles[2] = new CProfile(758200,5,23);
}
```

Where CProfile is defined as :

```
#ifndef PROFILE_H
#define PROFILE_H

class CProfile
{
private: 
    int m_Experience;
    int m_TownhallLevel;
    int m_Trophies;
public:
    CProfile(void);
    CProfile(int,int,int);
    void PrintInfo(void);
};
#endif
```

Everything seems to be compiling fine but a NullReferenceException occurs during `*profiles  = new CProfile[8];`. I'm new to C++ and I can't seem to figure out how to properly instantiate a class. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: because you dereference the pointer `profiles` before initialising it - try a [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: Why allocating ? Why not using a STL container ?

Comment: Tip: What memory is the pointer `profiles` pointing to, before you dereference it in the second line of main?

Comment: You need to delete the pointers afterward, too.

Comment: "NullReferenceException" is a Java thing. Are you sure that's what you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your code does:

```
int main()
{ 
    CProfile **profiles; // define a pointer to a pointer-to-CProfile
    *profiles  = new CProfile[8]; // you dereference "profiles", but... wait, it was just pointing to anywhere
    profiles[0] = new CProfile(2000,2,4); // you are writing into "*profiles" again...
    profiles[1] = new CProfile(55000,6,50); // and so on
    profiles[2] = new CProfile(758200,5,23);
}
```

What you were probably meaning:

```
int main()
{
     CProfile* profiles[8]; // define an array of 8 pointers to CProfile
     // assign pointers to unnamed objects to your array
     profiles[0] = new CProfile(2000,2,4);
     profiles[1] = new CProfile(55000,6,50);
     profiles[2] = new CProfile(758200,5,23);
}
```

Eventually, I suggest to ask yourself if you could go with another design: is strictly necessary to your allocation that `CProfiles` objects are dynamically allocated by `new`?

For example, you could use an `std::vector` or `std::array` to hold your profiles. That is what you may really had in mind:

```
int main()
{
    // profiles1 is an array of profiles built without any dynamic allocation
    CProfile profiles1[] = { CProfile(2000,2,4), CProfile(55000,6,50), CProfile(758200,5,23)};

    // profiles2 is a vector of CProfile; 
    // the memory holding your objects is dynamically allocated, but your object aren't
    std::vector<CProfile> profiles2; // profiles is a container of CProfile
    profiles.emplace_back(2000,2,4); // add a CProfile(2000,2,4) at the end of my container
    profiles.emplace_back(55000,6,50); // add a CProfile(55000,6,50) at the end of my container
    profiles.emplace_back(758200,5,23);
}
```

Comment: I must have confused myself with the pointer concepts. It seems that I have managed to make it work like this. What would be the other alternatives in allocating my indexes with `new`?

Comment: @JerYango Two alternatives are shown in the last code snippet in my answer (edited)